# GridView with incomplete row item does not scroll

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, row-height, gridviewrow

I have a problem with my `GridView` when it receives incomplete row item number, it doesn't scroll anymore. My items are dynamic which are given by the server, I have 3 columns and if the number of `GridView` items are more than enough to enable `scrolling` and if the row item is 3, it works fine. For example (9 items):
[image: complete]

But if the third row has only 1 or 2 item/s, it doesn't scroll anymore (7 or 8 items):
[image: incomplete]

This has caused me headache more than excitement, my `GridView` in layout is:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

In my activity nothing much, just declaration and setting its adapter. Did I miss anything? I tried adding `verticalSpacing` and `padding` separately but nothing's changed.

**EDIT:**
This is the setup in the whole layout:

[image: whole_layout]

`Black` is a `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` and the last `ImageView` are aligned top and bottom respectively. Top `TextView` is below `FrameLayout`, bottom `TextView` is below top `TextView`. Now `GridView` is below bottom `TextView` and above `ImageView`, it should expand its height basing to the space left consumed between the first 3 elements and the bottom element. This is how it's setup in my layout.

I believe it's a layout problem more than in my code since I've done dozens of `ListView` and this has similar implementation.

**EDIT2:**
The layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SixthActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cover_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/cover_image_progressbar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/school_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_sns"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_telephone"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_email"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_twitter"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_line"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cover_frame"
        android:background="#f8f7f3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/brown"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_news"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/student_name"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_news"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_next_plan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/container_news"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_next"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/next_plan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mypage_footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/container_next_plan"
        android:background="#ACA899"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mypage_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't mind the `ImageView`s, I just took out their source. I needed to retain the setup from my actual layout. The code:

```
public class SixthActivity extends Activity {

    private Integer[] gridViewItem = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sixth);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item_module, gridViewItem);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sixth, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private Integer[] moduleList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            Integer[] moduleList) {
        super(context, resource, moduleList);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.moduleList = moduleList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvModuleName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.module_name);
        holder.tvModuleImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.module_image);

        holder.tvModuleName.setText("SAMPLESAMPLE");
        return row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView tvModuleImage;
        public TextView tvModuleName;
    }
}
```

The item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_module"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/module_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/module_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try to add numbers to `gridViewItem` to add items enough to trigger the scrolling just like in my screenshots, and try taking out 1 or 2 items at the bottom such that that row would be incomplete to replicate my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your server request should not block the UI thread. How do you get the server response and feed your adapter?

Comment: @Tim It does not, I only mentioned it to emphasize that my items are dynamic. My question really lies on either my layout or missing `GridView` attribute which I'm not sure of.

Comment: Your GridView declaration seems ok. I myself tried an example with 2 items in the last row and there was no scrolling problem. Hard to find the reason without code. If you can share the code, I can help more.

Comment: @Tim I edited my post. The `GridView` is not really fullscreen but rather adjusts to what's left between the first 3 elements at the top and the last element at the bottom.

Comment: I tried the layout you described. Still didn't see any problems. Please post the xml of the full layout and the adapter code. There may be a problem in your getView method.

Comment: @Tim I just added the layouts and code. Thanks in advance for giving time.

Comment: I tried your code and still no problems. GridView scrolls with no problem.

Comment: @Tim This is so weird, I tried it in my dummy activity but it scrolls fine. I think it's in my actual items, instead of these `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }`, I have an `ImageView` and a title in a `TextView` under it. These are being showed in my `item layout`. My mind is gonna blow!

Comment: Yes, it is weird. Send me your complete project and let me check it. ahmettimucin@gmail.com

Comment: That's the problem, I can't. It's proprietary, and I can't send also the exact images.

Comment: Hard to tell something helpful. I couldn't find any problems. You have to find it yourself.